# Bifurcating recursive calculation with redundant calculations

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

```
def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    
print T(4)
```

I need an effective way to print out the output of the function `T(n)` generated using the recurrence relation above. Is there any way to make the above code more efficient?

Sample output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you cannot use `functools.cache` or `functools.lru_cache` and if
you don't understand or want to use a decorator, as shown in another
answer, here a low-tech approach to [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Please note
that the `functools` approach is easier, more robust, etc. But
if you are not worried about all of that and just want simple code
that is radically faster than your current approach, this will work.

```
def T(n):
    if n not in T.cache:
        if n <= 0:
            T.cache[n] = 1
        else:
            T.cache[n] = T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    return T.cache[n]

# Initialize the cache.
T.cache = {}
```

Comment: If you change `T.cache = {0: 1}` you can get rid of the if :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Hah, good idea, although I think at least `{0: 1, -1: 1}` is needed. And I don't know whether the function should gracefully handle negative integers, so I'll leave those optimizations to the OP.

Comment: Is there a way to time the code and check how fast each code gives an output?

Comment: @Justin Yes, it's called profiling.

Comment: Oops, yeah I made a mistake there!

Comment: Is there any documentation on `.cache` that I could have a look at?

Comment: @Justin Probably, but not specifically. Most things in Python, including functions, are objects. Objects can have attributes. We are just giving the `T` function an attribute called `cache`, and it's a `dict` that we intend to use for memoization. Regarding timing/profiling, there are many ways to do that, including using Python profiling libraries. But if you want simple, you can just do it "manually" with the `time` library: `t0 = time.time() ; DO SOMETHING ; t1 = time.time() ; print(t1 - t0)`

Comment: So I used the profiling method that you mentioned, and apparently, your program takes more time to execute than mine... Not sure if I was doing it right, but could you look into it? (I got `4.76837158203125e-06` for yours and `4.76837158203125e-07` for mine if that helps)

Comment: @Justin Need more specifics to make those times meaningful: what did you measure? For example, your function will indeed be faster for low values of `n`, because it does not incur any caching costs. The big differences emerge for larger values of `n`; that's when the caching approach yields big benefits because the code doesn't have to repeatedly compute a result for an input it has already seen before.

Comment: @FMc - Yes, you're completely right. The program seems to work faster for larger values of `n`. I tested both programs using smaller values of `n`. Thanks for clarifying! (Btw, I tested using `n=25`, I got 5e-05 for yours, and 0.046 seconds for mine, so it works faster for larger values of `n`, as you mentioned.)

Comment: Also, can `n == 0 or n == 1`? Like the only difference would be that inputting negative values would result in an error, right?

Comment: @Justin Yes, if I understand you correctly. If you aren't worried about the function handling negative numbers gracefully, you can just initialize the cache as `{0: 1, -1: 1}` and then drop the `if-else` structure entirely, as noted in the comments above.

Answer (score 10):

One more option is to not recurse at all, but to instead compute the sequence until we get the desired term. This not only avoids the original algorithm's exponential complexity; it also avoids the at least linear (in terms of counting values) memory complexity of memoization. (Recursion/memoization can also run into implementation-specific issues such as recursion depth errors or memory errors, which are not a concern with the code below.)

```
def T(n):
    if n<=0: return 1
    # Set a, b to T(-1), T(0)
    a, b = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):
        # Change a, b from T(i-1), T(i) to T(i), T(i+1)
        a, b = b, b+i*a
    # i=n-1 set b to T(n)
    return b
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use an [`if "__name__" == __main__:`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/231410) guard.

From Python 3.2 you can use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) and from Python 3.9 you can use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) to memoize the function calls, to only call `T` \$O(n)\$ times. Which is a fancy name for caching the input and output of the function. The way this works is by wrapping a function. Each time the decorated function is called we compare the arguments to the keys in a cache:

- if there is a match we return the value, and
- if there is no match we call the function to get the return value. Store the returned value in the cache and return the returned value to the caller.

Since you're using Python 2, we can make this function ourselves. We can use a closure to build a decorator function to hold the cache.

```py
def cache(fn):
    def inner(*args):
        try:
            return CACHE[args]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        CACHE[args] = value = fn(*args)
        return value
    CACHE = {}
    return inner
```

```py
@cache
def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I was wondering if you had something for Python 2.7... I wanted the solution to make use of only one recursive invocation of the function T. (The current one invokes the function T twice.) I'm looking for something simple and easy to understand...

Comment: @Justin My answer above does have something for Python 2.7. Please read the part that says "Since you're using Python 2". Asking to change code from calling a function twice to only once is not part of what Code Review is about.

Comment: Ah yes, the rest of the answer just loaded for me. I guess this works, but I would like the code to be shorter. I do not understand some of the complicated functions that Python has to offer and I was hoping for something simple and efficient.

Comment: Also, isn't changing code from calling a function twice to only once making the code more efficient? I didn't know how to do that, so I asked it here. Is there anywhere else I could ask?

Comment: @Justin There is a difference between "how can I make my code more efficient" and "how can I do this in Python". Code Review is about the former question where you are asking the latter.

Comment: But... I'm clearly asking for my code to be made more efficient... I just didn't want a complicated response.

Comment: @Justin You're asking for the code to be short, effectiveness has nothing to do with length.

Comment: By short, I meant concise... sorry!